# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}\leq 3$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, induction

Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}\leq 3$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

I proved it by induction:

"$n=1$"   $ \quad \sum_{k=0}^{1}{\frac{1}{k!}}\leq 3 \quad  \checkmark$

"$n \implies n+1$": $$\quad \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{\frac{1}{k!}}\leq 3 \\ \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}\right)+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\leq 3 \\ $$$$3+\overbrace{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}^{\geq 0}\leq 3 \\$$ That's of course true.

Comment: Are you claiming that $3$ plus something positive is smaller than $3$?

Comment: Oh, you're right, totally missed that. What's wrong?

Comment: can't use induction, sorry

Comment: Why's not possible?

Comment: @cmk I don't think so.... seems he/she is claiming that 3 plus something non-negative is at most 3

Comment: Why don't you try comparing it to the power series of $e^x$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic because $\frac{1}{(n+1)!} > 0$. you need a stronger induction hypothesis. for example, if you want to prove $x < x+1$, you can't first do $x < x+2$ and then try to show $x+2 < x+1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 No, they wrote that $3$ plus something strictly positive is at most $3$, which is wrong. They just made a mistake.

Comment: @cmk I know that. reread my comment. your first comment was wrong.

Comment: @mathworker21 It is not wrong. It is a critique of the very last line alone.

Comment: @cmk it's a wrong/inapplicable critique. they never said "smaller than 3" and they said $\ge 0$ rather than "positive".

Comment: They wrote $3+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\leq 3,$ which is wrong. I told them that line is wrong because $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}>0$ for any $n$. It is obvious that writing $3+\epsilon\leq 3$ is wrong if $\epsilon>0$. I understand your comments, but I was not even talking about that point. I don't even understand why you are being so insistent on this; it doesn't matter.

Comment: @cmk, I agree with you that your very first comment was appropriate.  By the way, it does say "greater or equal" but obviously that term $1/(n+1)!$ is positive and not equal to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k!}\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n\prod_{i=2}^k\frac1i\\
&\le2+\sum_{k=2}^n\prod_{i=2}^k\frac12\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{2^{k-1}}\\
&<2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{2^{k-1}}\\
&=2+\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}\\
&=3
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

For any finite $n$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} < e < 3.$$

**UPDATE**

$$1+1+\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n! }< 1 + 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = 1+2 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} <3.$$

Comment: i didn't downvote, but period should be inside double dollar signs

Comment: I think this is done prior to finding out that $e$ bounds the sum

Comment: Okay, but how do you know that $e<3$ (It is, but this seems to be using a fact about $e$ to prove a fact about $e$)

Comment: Well there is no context given for the question.  You are right, though, this probably appears in a calculus text on the way to developing the formula for $e$ or $e^x$.

Comment: @mathworker21,  thanks, moved the period.

Comment: mjw, how do you get $1 + 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = 1+2 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$?

Comment: The formula for a geometric series is $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{1-a^{k+1}}{1-a}$.  In this case $a=1/2$.

Comment: To derive the formula, multiply both sides of the formula by $(1-a)$.  This is known as a telescoping series, because only the first and last terms remain.

Comment: $(1-a)  \cdot (1+a+a^2 +a^3 + \cdots + a^n) = 1 \cdot 1 - a \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot a - a \cdot a + 1 \cdot a^2 - a \cdot a^2 + 1 \cdot a^3 \cdots - a^{n+1} = \phantom{0} 1-a^{n+1}$

Comment: The comment a few back should read $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$  The exponent is $n+1$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}<1+1+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{3^k}=1+1+\frac34$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+ \cdots$$ $$ < 1+1+\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4} +\frac{1}{4\cdot 5}+ \cdots$$ $$ = 1 + 1 +\left (1-\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right) + \left (\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\cdots$$ $$ = 1+1 +1 =3.$$

Answer (score 1):

That's not a correct proof.

Just because $x<3$ does *not* mean $x+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}<3$ as well. For instance, if $x=2.999999$ and $n=4$ this fails.

To solve this question, one way would be to note that for $n>1,\frac{1}{n!}\le\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ so we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}=1+1+\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}\le2+\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{i(i-1)}=2+\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i}=3$$

where the last equality comes from the fact that we have a telescoping sum of the form 
$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots$$

Comment: when did he/she claim $x < 3$ implies $x+\frac{1}{(n+1)!} < 3$? They claimed $3+\frac{1}{(n+1)!} < 3$, which is still false, but not a special case of the false thing you wrote

Comment: i'm explaining why their entire 'proof by induction' dies no matter how hard you try if you take P(n) to be the premise "the sum of the first n terms is less than 3"

Answer (score 1):

For each $k$ we have $${1\over (k+1)!}<{1\over 2k!}$$

So

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{\frac{1}{k!}}=1+ 1+{1\over 2!} +{1\over 3!}+...+{1\over (n+1)!}$$
$$<2+{1\over 2\cdot 1!} +{1\over 2\cdot 2!}+...+{1\over 2\cdot n!}$$
$$=2+{1\over 2}\Big(\underbrace{1+{1\over 2!} +{1\over 3!}+...+{1\over n!}}_{<3-1}\Big)$$
$$<2+{3-1\over 2} <3$$

Comment: You would prove that $e<2.5$. There must be something wrong.

Comment: @ajotatxe how does this prove $e < 2.5$?

Comment: Well, it would prove that $e\le 2.5$. Note that $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac1{k!}<1+\frac32$ implies that $e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\le1+\frac32$.